# How to get wireless working in XP x64 without drivers

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, drivers

I've looked high and low for 6 hours now, and found no drivers for the built in wireless on a N-Alvorix-RS880-uATX board. they got them for vista and 7, but not xp. The card in question is: ralink tech 80211n wireless LAN card.

Can I use a generic driver or something to make it work?

Comment: Could you please try to give more informations about your wireless card ? I can't find any built-in wireless lan card in [your motherboard's specifications](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02560084).

Comment: Here ya go friend, this is my desktop PC specs: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02640178&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5035348&prodTypeId=12454

Comment: HP doesn't really want to describe this Wireless Lan card in a more precise way. Could you please try to follow [these steps there](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/) and tell me your results. The Product ID and Vendor ID are really useful for drivers research, you'll just have to find the unknown networking controller device inside your Device Manager under XP.

Comment: You might have to accept that the device is not supported by your operating system.  I wouldn't be shocked if that was the case, Windows XP x64 is a very ugly cousin when it comes to x64 support ( program support is non-existant ).

Comment: I'm with Axel on this one.... I see no information about an integrated wireless card on this board.  Maybe if you provided the make and model of your PC, then we can help find the drivers on this. If it is a PCI card, then you can just look at the card.

Comment: Oops!  My bad.... caught your comment after I clicked Add Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HP seems to don't reveal more details about their PCI Express Wireless Lan Card, we should try to figure out first which card you've got.

I'd suggest you to retrieve some unique identifiers : The `Product ID` and the `Vendor ID` stored inside your device's read only memory.

You have to follow these steps under Windows XP :

- Open the `Start Menu`, right click on `My Computer`, then click on `Manage`.
- A new window will open up, choose `Device Manager` on the left pane of that window.
- You should see a list of every devices you have inside your machine, find an Unknown Device with a big yellow Question Mark, with the name of `Network Controller` :

  [image]
- Right-click on it, click on `Properties`.
- Go to the `Details` tab, and choose `Device Instance Id` inside the combo box, just under the Network Controller title.

  [image]

Now you can see `VEN_` followed by your `Vendor ID` and `DEV_` followed by your `Product ID`.
All you have to do is telling me these identifiers by writing a comment for this question, or you can also try to search "ProductID XXXX VendorID YYYY" on Google to find at least your Wireless LAN Card model, then you will have more luck into finding a working 64 bits version for Windows XP.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP 64 bit is more Server 2003 64 bit than XP 32 bit.  See if you can find are 200x 64 bit drivers.

Comment: Windows Server 2003 drivers will not work for Windows XP.

Comment: he said he had XP 64 bit, so yes they will

Answer (score 0):

The integrated network card is a Realtek RTL8105E. Here are drivers for Windows XP 32/64 bit:

http://www.realtek.cz/realtek-download.php?realtek=RTL8105E&system=1

EDIT: My bad.... I thought he needed the integrated NIC. The wireless card is a RaLink controller.  Try this link:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=pv-83740-1

Comment: I'm afraid that OP is asking for the Wireless Lan Controller, not the Ethernet one, the Wireless card is not integrated, it's just a PCI Express card as the documentation said.